# How can I create a WPF behavior that refers to multiple controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ScrollViewer that contains a large image. I want the user to be able to hold the mouse down and drag the image to move it side to side, and I'm trying to implement this using a Behavior. The problem is that the mouse down event doesn't seem to be able to fire on the ScrollViewer when a user presses down on the mouse button. With a code behind, I would handle that event on the image, but with a behavior that is only attached to one control I don't know how to approach this issue.

What approach should I use to create a System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior that attaches to both objects?

Comment: Just to clarify: are you saying that you want to start the image dragging even when the user mouses down not on the image but on the scrollviewer?

Comment: The image should take up the entire contents of the ScrollViewer, so the other than the scroll bars, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MouseLeftButtonDown event is raised just fine on the ScrollViewer. The problem is that the ScrollViewer is handling the event itself (e.Handled = true). And since it is already handled your behavior do not receive it.

Depending on what you are doing you might be able to just use the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event instead. This way it doesn't matter if the ScrollViewer will handle it since the Behavior is receiving it first.

You could also try to use the Drag&Drop events directly. But I'm not sure if that will work.

Comment: Do you mean that the Image is handling the event itself before it gets to the scroll viewer?

Comment: No ... the ScrollViewer is handling the event if I recall correctly. Propably through the MouseLeftButtonDown override. Not exactly sure how and why but in the very end you do not get notified when you subscribe to the event since it is somehow already handled by someone.

Comment: @harri OK. I was assuming that it was handled by the Image control in a way similar to Javascript event bubbling.

Comment: Well ... I don't know about js event bubbling (as a matter of fact I don't know much about js at all). But it is propably something like that. WPF is using a two pass event routing (propably called differently but u know what I mean, right?). At first events are tunneled down the visual tree beginning at the top node (most likly the main window). Those are the preview events. When the event reaches the control that actually raised it the direction is reversed and the event is bubbled up the visual tree till it reaches the root node (window).

Comment: If someone intercepts the event along the way by setting the handled flag the event will no longer be routed. When the scroll viewer is handling the mouse event you do not get it anymore. Even though you are at the same level, the scoll viewer itself is called first and you are stuck. When you subscribe to the tunneling event you will get notifyied before the ScrollViewer have a chance to handle it. You have to be carefull wih tunneling events though:

Comment: If you have, lets say, a button nested in the image (what is not possible but anyway) you would get weired behavior by handling the preview event. The button also will "swallow" the event to prevent parent controls to react on the click when the user is using the button. When you are using the tunneling event instead of the bubbeling event you wouldn't know that the user actually clicked the button, start your panning operation AND execute whatever it is that the button does. Thats propably the reason why the scoll viewer is handling the event. I hope that was not to confusing :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to attach to an element to be able to add an event handler to it.  If your `AssociatedObject` is a `ScrollViewer` then you might be able to get a reference to the image like this:

```
var image = AssociatedObject.Content as Image;
```

and then you can add a mouse event handler:

```
image.MouseLeftButtonDown += (s, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Clicked!");
```

So the object you are attached to, your associated object, is your "home base", but you can work with any object you can get your hands on up to and including using `VisualTreeHelper` to walk the visual tree.